# Lua 5.3 max variable name length

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

I'm doing a report about Lua 5.3 for the college and have a topic where I need talk about variable names. I already consulted the documentation, but the info that I need isn't there.

What I want to know is how many characters a variable name can have in Lua 5.3? Exists some max limit or the size does not matter to the interpreter?

Comment: AFAIK. the length of variable name is  unlimited,

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: There is no such a thing as a maximum variable name in Lua 5.3. 
Variables are indexes on a table, and those indexes are zero terminated C strings, that in theory have no limit on their sizes.